# Does the Jack-of-All-Trades edge help with Weird Science devices?

Tags: savage-worlds

In Savage Worlds Deluxe, the Jack-Of-All-Trades edge gives the following benefits:

> Any time he makes an unskilled roll for a Smarts-based skill, he may do so at d4 instead of the usual d4–2.

Does the Jack-Of-All-Trades edge also applies to the Weird Science roll made when using a Weird Science device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Yes

The rules for handing Weird Science devices directly reference the unskilled rolls rule, so Jack-Of-All-Trades applies, as Weird Science in Smarts-based. In addition, it is never mentioned anywhere that you are not allowed to buy or roll an Arcane skill without the corresponding Arcane Background.

Comment: At least in SWADE it is pretty clear that you can only use arcane stuff if you got the corresponding arcane background. I don't have deluxe near me to check how its written there but I always played it that way. You need the arcane background to use the arcane stuff

Comment: @ChoTimberwolf The rules for Weird Science in the SWD only work if you _are_ allowed to roll Weird Science without having it; otherwise, you couldn't hand devices over to other people. The question of whether you are allowed to _level_ it without the AB is what isn't specified at all.

Comment: SWADE 153 Arcane devices says that the weird science of the creator gets used. But weird science was changed between deluxe and swade I think, so you are probably right